# Tomcat stopped accepting input and is crashed

Tags: apache, tomcat, soap

I have deployed SOAP Service using tomcat. I pushed a request to the SOAP service and it worked. But when i submitted bulk request., tomcat crashed.

I can see below error in log files:-

```
  SEVERE: Endpoint ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=7106] ignored exception: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
    java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:384)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:450)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:421)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.acceptSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:61)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.acceptSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:408)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:71)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:685)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
    WARNING: Reinitializing ServerSocket
Jun 5, 2014 6:43:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint acceptSocket
SEVERE: Endpoint null ignored exception: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
    at java.net.ServerSocket.createImpl(ServerSocket.java:255)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.getImpl(ServerSocket.java:205)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:185)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:50)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.initEndpoint(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:293)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.acceptSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:469)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:71)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:685)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Jun 5, 2014 6:43:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint acceptSocket
WARNING: Restarting endpoint
Jun 5, 2014 6:43:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint acceptSocket
SEVERE: Endpoint null shutdown due to exception: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
    at java.net.ServerSocket.createImpl(ServerSocket.java:255)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.getImpl(ServerSocket.java:205)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:185)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:50)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.initEndpoint(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:293)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.acceptSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:481)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:71)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:685)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Jun 5, 2014 6:43:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable run
SEVERE: Caught exception (java.lang.ThreadDeath) executing org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread@4d8d50, terminating thread
```

Can some body tell me cause and solution to the problem.